# How do I call a perl process that is already running from another script?

Tags: perl, sockets, signals

Problem:
scriptA.cgi is sitting in an infinite loop and handling an open socket to a Flash client.
scriptB.cgi is called from the web, does what it needs to do and then needs to inform scriptA to send a message to the client.

Is this possible? I'm stuck on how to have scriptB identify the instance of scriptA that is sitting there with the socket connection, rather than launching one of its own.

all thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Edited my answer to provide more info.

Comment: cool... so the only thing I'm still not clear on is how to actually make the call to the running process. Assuming I have its ID, how do I make a call to that script? Ideally there would be a method in the script that I could call. I don't even need to pass params to it, I just need it to know it's time to wake up and work.

Comment: See mobrules answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977462/how-do-i-call-a-perl-process-that-is-already-running-from-another-script/1977516#1977516 for a short example. If you want further advice I suggest asking a new question. Something like *"How do I send and receive signals with perl?"*

Comment: You can interrupt a Perl script and make a run a subroutine called a *signal handler* by using the `kill` command from another Perl script (or the Un*x `kill` command from a shell script or command line). See my answer or http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlipc#Signals for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the communication needs are simple, this is a good application for signals.

**Edited** to store process id from scriptA and read it in scriptB -- scripts A and B have to agree on a name.

```
 # script B
 do_scriptB_job();
 if (open(my $PID_FILE, "<", "scriptA.pid.file")) {
   $process_id_for_scriptA = <$PID_FILE>;
   close $PID_FILE;
   kill 'USR1', $process_id_for_scriptA;  # makes scriptA run the SIGUSR1 handler
 }


 # script A
 open(my $PID_FILE, ">", "scriptA.pid.file");
 print $PID_FILE $$;
 close $PID_FILE;
 my $signaled = 0;
 $SIG{"USR1"} = \sub { $signaled = 1 } # simple SIGUSR1 handler, set a variable
 while ( in_infinite_loop ) {
     if ($signaled) {
         # this block runs only if SIGUSR1 was received 
         # since last time this block was run
         send_a_message_to_the_client();
         $signaled = 0;
     } else {
         do_something_else();
     }
 }
 unlink "scriptA.pid.file";   # cleanup
```

When script A receives a `SIGUSR1` signal, the script will be interrupted to run the `USR1` signal handler, setting `$signaled`. The thread of execution will then resume and the script can use the information.

Comment: You did not address this bit: *I'm stuck on how to have scriptB identify the instance of scriptA that is sitting there with the socket connection*

Comment: yeah... that's actually the part I'm lost on... once I have that, I can figure out the rest.

Comment: using signals as above really only works if the cgi scripts are viewed by only one browser.

Answer (score 2):

Have scriptA store it's pid somwhere (in a db with some kind of id), then scriptB can look up the pid in the db and send a signal to scriptA.

Edit:
Answering question asked in comment

The pid of the process can be found using perls builtin variables **$$** or **$PID** or **$PROCESS_ID** depending on how old your perl is.

See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for details.

I hope this is the ID you where looking for. If not you'll have to find a way to separate the different scriptA instances. (Perhaps by session id, or socket. Here I cant help you further)

Comment: Edited answer to provide more info.

Answer (score 2):

Other people have mentioned how to get the PID (if you didn't fork() it yourself, just have the other-process write it... somewhere... that both processes know how to get it. or walk the process table, but that's a horrible solution and completely unscalable beyond a singleton).

Since you note that any thoughts are welcome, note that `perldoc perlipc` explains a variety of mechanisms you might use for the actual communication:

```
NAME
    perlipc - Perl interprocess communication (signals, fifos, pipes, safe
    subprocesses, sockets, and semaphores)

DESCRIPTION
    The basic IPC facilities of Perl are built out of the good old Unix
    signals, named pipes, pipe opens, the Berkeley socket routines, and SysV
    IPC calls. Each is used in slightly different situations.
```

Answer (score 0):

Domain sockets: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/IPC/unix.html
?

Answer (score 0):

I was tempted to answer, 'send signals' or 'use some kind of IPC to talk between apps' but, a far easier and scalable approach is to use a sqlite (or other) database that all scripts can talk to,

ScriptA.cgi would poll the database by doing something like 'SELECT event FROM events WHERE clientID=?'.

ScriptB.cgi would simply insert a row into the events table with the right clientID.

That avoids all of the 'find the pid' mess and also mean that you don't get the blocking IO problems you would get with named pipes or if one script crashed.

Comment: I already have a DB in the mix, but I'm not certain this approach is ideal because then the process that is being signaled will need to pound the db every 100 milliseconds looking for a cue to do whatever it's supposed to do.